# I want to build a program in which i want to recognize the faces in video select the particular face and apply mask to selected face

Tags: opencv, tensorflow, image-processing, face-recognition

This application should do following.
Step 1 :- Detect all faces in video frame.
Step 2 :- Here now user will select the faces to which it want to apply mask(Funny animation or emotes).
Step 3 :- Apply mask (Funny animation or emotes) to selected face & rest of faces in video frames will kept as it is.


eg :- how snapchat does but here will are applying mask to only selected face.
Technology need to use are (python, opencv, tensorflow or keras)
Please help. Thankyou.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest possible way in order to detect faces from a video is to implement face detection is by using `Haar cascades in OpenCV and Python`. That approach could be found [in here](https://towardsdatascience.com/face-detection-in-2-minutes-using-opencv-python-90f89d7c0f81).

In such away, you can return given a video all the detected faces (this is a standard approach that works nicely, though it is far from being the state of the art). Your second step is to create an Interface where you will show all the detected faces. [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iMBj_z0nwTQ) you can find some of the standard `GUI Frameworks` in `Python` that can help you in your quest.

Comment: Yes I had already written a scrip to detect the faces using "Haar cascades in OpenCV" as you said now my problem is i want to select any particular face from all detected faces let's say 5 faces has been detected (F1, F2, F3, F4, & F5) and i want to select only face F3 to apply mask on it. It should happen in video not just in single image, so how to achieve that, as far my knowledge we need CNN to recognize the selected face and apply mask to only select face avoiding rest of faces which appear in given video frame.

Comment: The definition of your problem is not that clear. How could the user pick the faces he wants among the detected ones? You should state clearly how that process needs to be done.

Comment: Let's suppose all detected faces are assigned with labels and i had provided a drop-down menu listing all labels from there the user can select the desired labels ( representing  targeted face)

Comment: So you want to replace the detected daces with the detected face?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good example of how to start with face detection, you basically can use code from the tutorial and build masks on top of this app: https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/02/26/face-detection-with-opencv-and-deep-learning/